# Is it possible to bulk delete from a many-many association with HQL?

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

And if so, what is the syntax?

Assume that I want an instance of Foo to be unassociated from all instances of Bar:
In SQL it would simply be:

```
delete from FOO_BAR_MAPPING
where FOO_ID = ?
```

In HQL, I assumed it would be something like:

```
delete from Bar.foos foos
where foos.id = :id
```

(where foos is a mapped collection of Foo)

But appears to be wrong, giving:

```
org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Bar.foos is not mapped
```

Is this even possible with HQL?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To answer your specific question, no, as far as I'm aware it's not possible with HQL.

I think you're mixing SQL and HQL a little bit here. In SQL, you indeed "delete" records, and of course hibernate will ultimately do that as well. However Hibernate/HQL is designed from an object-oriented mindset, so "delete" in this context means you are deleting objects, not associations. Typically you'd do something like follows:

```
Foo f = session.get(Foo.class, id);
f.getBars().clear();
session.merge(f);
```

This retrieves the object by the id you specified, and removes all Bar associations by clearing it's collection. Obviously you have to have the Foo-Bars association mapped in the proper direction for this to work.

Comment: Note that this would only delete the association table entry, not the element on the end.  To do that, you would need to have delete-orphans turned on.

Answer (score 1):

Removing associations alone is not possible with HQL. What you can do, however, is either:

A) Assuming you're doing it for a single Foo and your cascade is set appropriately, you can load that `Foo` instance, clear its collection of `bars` and save it.

B) If you're trying to clear `bars` from multiple `Foos` you can map an SQL query instead of HQL