# How to delete an entry from joined table of many-to-many relationship in grails

Tags: grails, many-to-many, hql, grails-orm, grails-2.0

I have two domain objects

```
Class Attachment{
    static hasMany = [mailDrafts: MailDraft];
}

Class MailDraft{
  static hasMany = [attachments: Attachment]
   static belongsTo = Attachment
}
```

It has created the three tables

```
1)attachment
2)mail_draft 
3)attachment_mail_drafts

attachment_mail_drafts: id, mail_draft_id
```

Now, I wnat to write a a HQL query `to delete an entry from the table 'attachment_mail_drafts' where 'attachment_id' is 4`, So what is the query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do this with HQL, you can read more why [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1201690/is-it-possible-to-bulk-delete-from-a-many-many-association-with-hql).
Instead you would do the following:

```
def a = Attachment.get(4)
a.mailDrafts.clear()
a.save()
```

Answer (score 3):

It seems that in HQL you can only remove objects, removing associations is not possible. You could use raw SQL or use GORM method removeFrom:

```
def attachment = Attachment.get(1)
def mailDraft = attachment.mailDrafts.find { it.id = 4 }
attachment.removeFromMailDrafts(mailDraft).save(flush: true)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could implement the m:n collections avoiding the hasMany/belongsTo technique using the approach [explained](http://www.infoq.com/presentations/GORM-Performance) by Mr Burt Beckwith, this improves the performance and can help you to safely delete the 'attachment_mail_drafts' entity that you [need](https://mrpaulwoods.wordpress.com/2011/02/07/implementing-burt-beckwiths-gorm-performance-no-collections/).