# How to clear collection associations in JPQL?

Tags: hibernate, jpa-2.0

Consider the following JPQL query:

```
UPATE FOO f SET f.bars = NULL
```

Running this statement will yield the exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.QueryException: collections not assignable in update statements [UPATE FOO f SET f.bars = NULL ]
```

What I'm trying to do is to sever in *one* statement *all* associations between FOO and BAR. Instead of iterating over each FOO to set the bars collections to null. That's much faster.

Unfortunately the association is unidirectional - so there's no *foo* attribute in a Bar entity. Hence JPQL can clear the other side of the association.

Invoking NEW does not work either:

```
UPATE FOO f SET f.bars = NEW java.util.ArrayList()
```

This results in a different exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: node to traverse cannot be null!
```

It's clear JPA/Hibernate won't allow a collection association to be set to null. But maybe somebody in here knows a workaround ?

Answer (score 0):

Run clear on the collection suppose to remove all relations .
You cannot do this in HQL, but use session.get will help with performance.
see this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1201690/is-it-possible-to-bulk-delete-from-a-many-many-association-with-hql)

Comment: That's right. But I'm trying to do that in one JPQL statement for the sake of performance.

Answer (score 0):

JPQL update and delete queries apply to entities of a single entity class only so what you are trying to achieve is not possible. However as user1495181 suggested you can call clear on collection. When the entity manager is flushed at the end of transaction, all the link updation (here the links is deleted) statements would be added to prepared statement batch and send to database.

Comment: Is there any particular reason it is not possible ?